# Is it true that drinking calcium carbonate or potash can help with stomach acidity?

Tags: survival, health

Is it true that drinking calcium carbonate or potash extracted from wood ash can help with stomach acidity ?
one of my friends told me this but i cant swallow it

Answer (score 1):

Both will partially neutralize hydrochloric acid in the stomach but I am not sure I would call that "help". A stomach is supposed to be very acidic. The burning sensation is acid leaking past the spincter muscle into the esophagus, not the stomach. I have used a little calcium bicarbonate in water to rinse acid out of the esophagus with success.

Answer (score 0):

Calcium carbonate is the main ingredient in TUMS and most antacid pills.

Wood ash, however is going have more with potash,  lye (Sodium/Potassium hydroxied. Calcium oxide.

Probably won't hurt you in small quantities, but tastes awful.

From wikipedia

> Much wood ash contains calcium carbonate as its major component, representing 25[5] or even 45 percent.[6] Less than 10 percent is potash, and less than 1 percent phosphate; there are trace elements of iron, manganese, zinc, copper and some heavy metals.[5] However, these numbers vary, as combustion temperature is an important variable in determining wood ash composition.[3] All of these are, primarily, in the form of oxides.[3]